# How to fetch google calender into android app

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I need to make users login through Google, and then show them calendar events.
first part is completed but i don't know how to develop the second part, can someone help me with the Google calender part.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would answer this for those who are really stuck and dont know where to start like I was as there are very poor instructions out there.

1- Firstly go to [this link](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) and follow all the instructions to set up your project with google.

2- Once you get to "Configure your app" you are likely to be stuck as the code does not work

3- [Download mercurical](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads/) so that you can download example google projects, e.g. the calendar.

4- Open your command window by typing 'cmd' into your start menu and pressing enter (for windows)

5- Navigate to this link -> /code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout?repo=samples (Remember http: [dont have enough reputation])

6- Then copy and paste 'hg clone //code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/' (Remember http: [dont have enough reputation]) into the terminal window. Wait for it to finish downloading (will take a few minutes)

7- Look at the path you downloaded the file to: eg, c:\Users>

8- Go to that directory in your folders and you will have the example apps.

You will have to import it into Eclipse or your prefered environment. And now at least you can see code and figure out how to use it from there! Just wish someone somewhere could of been kind enough to start a buddy off with these simple steps.

refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885931/2771869

Comment: thanks @mohammad rababah...for showing me some light..i really appreciate it.